# Is the Jaccard distance between probability vectors a metric?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, inequalities

Let **X** and **Y** be probability vectors, meaning that **X** = $[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]^T$, where $x_i\leq 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=1$ (**Y** is defined similarly).

Define the Jaccard distance as

\begin{equation}
    J_d = 1 - \frac{\textbf{X}\cdot\textbf{Y}}{\textbf{X}\cdot \textbf{X}+ \textbf{Y}\cdot\textbf{Y} - \textbf{X}\cdot\textbf{Y}}
\end{equation}

Is $J_d$ a proper distance (i.e., metric)?

Comment: Hi! I think you should add your own thoughts and work on this question.

Comment: Seems similar to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18084/is-the-jaccard-distance-a-distance (not exactly because that question has cardinalities of sets, but similar methods probably work).

Comment: It looks like a different question (with different answer).

Comment: Oops, you are right Fedor!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Jaccard distance a distance?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18084/is-the-jaccard-distance-a-distance)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen The Jaccard distance is indeed a metric when applied with bits vectors. My question was regarding the application of this distance with probability vectors (i.e., distribution vectors).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. For fixed $Y$, fixed $Z=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ with $\sum z_i=0$, and small $t$ we have $J_d(Y\pm tZ, Y)\sim t^2 \frac{Z\cdot Z}{Y\cdot Y}$, but $$J_d(Y-tZ,Y+tZ)\sim 4t^2\frac{Z\cdot Z}{Y\cdot Y}>J_d(Y-tZ,Y)+J_d(Y,Y+tZ).$$

Comment: I believe the vector **Z** should be constrained such that **Y** + t **Z** remains in the space of probability distribution vectors. If this constraint is applied to **Z**, does this triangular inequality remain violated?

Comment: If all coordinates of $Y$ are positive and $\sum z_i=0$, it remains for small values if $t$.

Comment: If you want a concrete example, take $Y=(0.5,0.5)$, $Z=(0.1,-0.1)$ and $t=1$ in Fedor's answer. You obtain $(0.5,0.5)$, $(0.4,0.6)$ and $(0.6,0.4)$ that indeed violate the triangle inequality.