# Is the Jaccard distance between continuous vectors a metric?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, inequalities

Define the Jaccard distance between two continuous vectors $a, b\in [0,1]^p$ as
\begin{equation}
J(a,b) = 1 - \frac{\|a\odot b\|_1}{\|a\odot b\|_1+\|a-b\|_1}
\end{equation}
where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product (element-wise product).

Is it a metric? Note that $a,b \in [0,1]^p$ rather than $\{0,1\}^p$.

I've tried with the naive approach. After some messy algebra, I need to prove the following
\begin{equation}
\|a-b\|_1\|a\odot c\|_1\|b\odot c\|_1 + \|a-b\|_1\|b-c\|_1\|a\odot c\|_1 + \|a-b\|_1 \|b-c\|_1 \|a-c\|_1 + \|b-c\|_1\|a\odot b\|_1 \|a\odot c\|_1 + \|a-b\|_1\|b-c\|_1\|a\odot c\|_1 \geq \|a-c\|_1\|a\odot b\|_1 \|b\odot c\|_1.
\end{equation}

Comment: What do you mean by $ab$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Please see the edited version. It is the Hadamard product between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: you do realise that $a-b$ is of different length than $a\odot b.$ Whats the motivation for this definition?

Comment: $a \odot b$ is the element-wise product, not inner product. So $a\odot b$ and $a-b$ are both of length $p$, right?

Comment: see also: https://mathoverflow.net/q/18084/11260 --- _Is the Jaccard distance a distance?_

Comment: That question $a,b\in \{0,1\}^p$ and one can utilize set algebra. Here the setting is quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All norms are supposed to be $1$-norms. Rewrite $J(a,b)$ as
$$
  J(a,b)=\frac{\|a-b\|}{\|a-b\|+\|a\odot b\|}.
$$

Notice that
$$
  \|b\odot c\|=\sum_i b_ic_i
  =\sum_i\bigl((b_i-a_i)c_i+a_ic_i\bigr)
  \leq\sum_i|b_i-a_i|+\sum_ia_ic_i=\|a-b\|+\|a\odot c\|.
$$
Similarly,
$$
  \|a\odot b\|\leq \|b-c\|+\|a\odot c\|.
$$
Hence we have
$$
  J(a,b)+J(b,c)
  =\frac{\|a-b\|}{\|a-b\|+\|a\odot b\|}+\frac{\|b-c\|}{\|b-c\|+\|b\odot c\|}\\
  \geq \frac{\|a-b\|}{\|a-b\|+\|b-c\|+\|a\odot c\|}
    +\frac{\|b-c\|}{\|b-c\|+\|a-b\|+\|a\odot c\|}\\
  =\frac{\|a-b\|+\|b-c\|}{\|a-b\|+\|b-c\|+\|a\odot c\|}
  \geq \frac{\|a-c\|}{\|a-c\|+\|a\odot c\|}=J(a,c),
$$
where the last inequality follows from $\|a-b\|+\|b-c\|\geq \|a-c\|$.